# Meaning of id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)

Tags: mysql

Supposing I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE files (
    id_prod INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_rel INT UNSIGNED,
    name VARCHAR(250),
    other VARCHAR(200),
    UNIQUE INDEX(id_rel , name)
);
```

and I want to use an unique `query` to insert/update the data on this table:

```
INSERT INTO files (id_rel , name)
VALUES ('25', 'test')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

now, reading the MySQL manual I read about this:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)
```

so I thought my query should be:

```
INSERT INTO files (id_rel , name)
VALUES ('25', 'test')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id_prod = LAST_INSERT_ID(id), name = 'TESTED'
```

but which is the difference if I use only:

```
INSERT INTO files (id_rel , name)
VALUES ('25', 'test')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = 'TESTED'
```

?

I cannot understand the meaning of LAST_INSERT_ID(id). What is (id) and what it's supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only necessary if your application needs to call `LAST_INSERT_ID()` after performing the `INSERT`. Normally, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will only return a value if you actually inserted a new row into the table, not of there was a duplicate key and it updated the row instead.

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id):

> If *expr* is given as an argument to `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, the value of the argument is returned by the function and is remembered as the next value to be returned by `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

If you use the idiom you quoted, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will return either the ID of the new row that was inserted or the row that was updated.

Comment: Thank you very much! But if I don't need the LAST ID I inserted OR updated then this is unecessary, am I right?
The `WHERE id_prod = '$var_id'` I'd use on an `UPDATE` query is here replaced by the `ON DUPLICATE KEY`, if I correctly understad...

Comment: Yes, that's what "only necessary if" means.